# Is there a way to append query/route parameters with routerLink/router.navigate?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm displaying a list of items with search and pagination, and I'd like to keep existing query parameters when other parameters change.

So I could have something like `/items?page=3&size=10&title=Hey` and `router.navigate('RouteName', { title: 'Hello' })` would only change the title, keeping the page and size.

Is that currently possible in Angular2? Or, if not, could I somehow extend the router with this functionality, maybe expose an alternative method, lets say 'navigateSafely', that keeps parameters? And then `routerLink` for templates?

I've looked through the source code for the router but... I can't make heads or tails of it; the Instruction class itself seems overly complicated.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using? There is a new router since RC.0. You need to explicitely pass all parameters. If you want to keep some unchanged acquire them and pass them along unchanged.

Comment: I try to keep with the latest beta.

Comment: It's the same there as well but if you want concrete code the actual version is important. I guess you need to provide more details. It's different where the routerLink is (in the root component or "any" component or the component that was added by the current route, ...)

Comment: If some parameters have to be kept unchanged along navigation (unless the user decides to change) I would consider to set such parameters in a 'config.service' object which is passed around via Dependency Injection. I hope I have understood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router does not have any built-in method or setting to keep existing route parameters when navigating at the moment.

The router also can't be easily extended as far as I can tell; it's usage is more complex than a regular service.

If anything changes, I'll update this answer.

Here's the best way to do it using Underscore and RouteParams:

```
this._router.navigate([route, _.assign(this._params.params, { page: page })]);
```